# How can I generalise my code to find palindrome number for two numbers with more digits 4,5 or 6 and what can I do to make it work more quickly?

Tags: ruby

I want the palindrome code to work not just for 3 digit but for 4, 5 or 6 and how can I work more quickly?

```
to = 999
from = 100
palindroms = []
for i in from..to do
  p i
  for j in 1..to do
    k = i * j
    palindroms << k if k.to_s == k.to_s.reverse
  end
end
puts palindroms.max
```

Comment: Can please show some inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: How can I show if It's 4 digits or 5 digits or 6 digits, the largest palindromic number ?

Comment: What happens if you change the values of `to` and `from`?

Comment: Surely the largest n-digit palindromic number is just a sequence of 9s. So it's 999 for three digits, 9999 for four digits ... What are you _actually_ trying to work out?

Comment: yes if I change the value it does work but is there a way I can do so that I don't need to change the digit? it detects the digit and works quickly as it takes long time now.

Comment: Does it need to be a product? You code wouldn't find `929` for example, because it's prime.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```rb
class PalindromeGenerator
  def initialize(length)
    raise ArgumentError if length <= 1

    @length = length
  end

  def run
    length.odd? ? run_odd : run_even
  end

  private

  attr_reader :length

  def run_even
    halves.map { |half| "#{half}#{half.to_s.reverse}".to_i }
  end

  def run_odd
    halves.each_with_object([]) do |half, memo|
      middles.each do |middle|
        memo << "#{half}#{middle}#{half.to_s.reverse}".to_i
      end
    end
  end

  def halves
    half_length = length / 2
    min = 10**(half_length - 1)
    max = 10**half_length
    (min...max)
  end

  def middles
    (0..9)
  end
end
```

It builds the left halves of the palindrome from the given `length`. Then, it builds the palindrome list:

- If `length` is even, simply `map` and mirror the left half.
- If `length` is odd, for each half you have to build 10 palindromes by adding any number in the middle.

---

For instance, given `length = 5`:

- `half_length` is 2.
- The left halves are all numbers from 10 (`10**(2-1)`) to 99 (`10**2 - 1`).
- Since 5 is odd, the list can be built as follows:

  - `half = 10` -> `[10001, 10101, 10201, 10301, 10401, 10501, 10601, 10701, 10801, 10901]`
  - `half = 11` -> ...
  - ...

I think it could be optimized quite a bit, but it's already a lot better than a naive approach.

Answer (score 1):

A solution :

```rb
def palindrome(nb, exlude_zeros = true)
  raise ArgumentError, 'nb should be >= 1' if nb < 1
  num_permutation = nb / 2
  should_generate_middle_column = nb.odd?
  # Process
  if should_generate_middle_column
    # In this part we'll generate 101 111 121 131 141 151 161 171 181 191
    # The middle column is 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 for 1x1
    # Before generating the middle column we'll generate the permutation like in the else part.
    result = (0..9).to_a.repeated_permutation(num_permutation).collect do |arr|
      rev = arr.reverse
      (0..9).collect { |i| (arr.clone << i).concat(rev).join.to_i }
    end
    result.flatten!
  else
    # In this part we'll only find the permutations (for nb / 2) 
    # and mirror the permutations givin the palindrome.
    result = (0..9).to_a.repeated_permutation(num_permutation).collect do |arr|
        arr.concat(arr.reverse).join.to_i
    end
  end
  result.reject! { |i| i.to_s.size != nb } if exlude_zeros
  return result
end
```

You can call it like this :
palindrome(1)
palindrome(2)
palindrome(3)
etc...

It'll return the list of palindrome number of the size you specified as input number.

Comment: Given the size and complexity of the code, I hope it's much faster than `(10**(nb-1)...10**nb).select{ |i| i.to_s == i.to_s.reverse }`

Comment: Can you explain the code please. I am new to coding.

Comment: My first reaction was "My brain is so sick generating such code" but I tried your code that is waaaay easier than mine (with nb = 10) it's still running. My code took 0.79 second with nb = 10...

Can you test on your side ?

Comment: @Anu Basically, my goal is to generate the side that is "mirrored" in the palindrome using permutation. The number of mirrored digit is nb / 2 (it's an integer division).  There's a specific cas where only generating the mirrored part is not enough, when nb is odd. Because you don't have an even number of digit so I have to generate the middle column (my variable naming is wrong) during the mirrored part generation. With a drawing it'll be easier to explain, I'm not a native english ^^'

Comment: It's all good, your code is indeed *much* faster than mine (e.g. 180x for nb=6). It makes sense because you generate palindromes directly whereas my code simply test every possible number.

Comment: Your code is much faster than his code and it's way easier to understand than mine so it's a good solution too :)

Comment: But how do I check if a product of 4 digit number is a palindrome? At the moment it checks for 4 digits

Comment: `(your_product).to_s == (your_product).to_s.reverse`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not efficient, but the basic idea is to split the the number into digits array ([Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Integer.html#method-i-digits)), and check the halves:

```
n = 12421

digits = n.digits
digits[0...digits.size / 2] == digits.reverse[0...digits.size / 2]
#=> true
```

Comment: You can use `...` instead of `- 1`.

Comment: No, he means [exclusive ranges](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Range.html). "[Ranges] created using `...` exclude the end value". You should write `(0...digits.size / 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we wish to identify all palindromes between `from = 27` and `to = 3345`. Rather than examine each number between `from` and `to` in order to identify the palindromes, I will generate all the palindromes between `20` and `3999` recursively and combinatorially, and then use two binary searches to exclude all palindromes between `20` and `26` (i.e., `22` only) and all palindromes between `3346` and `3999`.

**Code**

```
def palindromes(from, to)
  arr = ranges(from, to).each_with_object([]) do |(n,f,t),arr|
    arr.concat(pals(n,f,t))
  end.map { |a| a.join.to_i }                                                                          
  is = arr.bsearch_index { |n| n >= from }
  ie = arr.bsearch_index { |n| n > to }
  ie = ie.nil? ? arr.size-1 : ie-1
  arr[is..ie]
end
```

```
def ranges(from, to)
  *a, from_first_digit = from.digits
  from_nbr_digits = a.size + 1
  *a, to_first_digit = to.digits
  to_nbr_digits = a.size + 1
  (from_nbr_digits..to_nbr_digits).each_with_object([]) { |ndigits, a|
    a << [ndigits, from_nbr_digits == ndigits ? from_first_digit : 1,
          to_nbr_digits == ndigits ? to_first_digit : 9] }
end
```

```
def pals(ndigits, first, last)
  case ndigits
  when 1
    (first..last).to_a
  when 2
    (first..last).map {|d| [d,d]}
  else
    a = pals(ndigits-2, 0, 9)
    (first..last).each_with_object([]) { |d,arr|
      a.each {|b| arr << [d,*b,d] } }
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
palindromes(27, 3345)
  #=> [                    33,   44,   55,   66,   77,   88,   99,
  #     101,  111,  121,  131,  141,  151,  161,  171,  181,  191,
  #     202,  212,  222,  232,  242,  252,  262,  272,  282,  292,
  #     ...
  #     909,  919,  929,  939,  949,  959,  969,  979,  989,  999,
  #    1001, 1111, 1221, 1331, 1441, 1551, 1661, 1771, 1881, 1991,
  #    2002, 2112, 2222, 2332, 2442, 2552, 2662, 2772, 2882, 2992,
  #    3003, 3113, 3223, 3333]

palindromes(1141, 3345)
  #=> [            1221, 1331, 1441, 1551, 1661, 1771, 1881, 1991,
  #    2002, 2112, 2222, 2332, 2442, 2552, 2662, 2772, 2882, 2992,
  #    3003, 3113, 3223, 3333]

require 'time'

t = Time.now 
(a = palindromes(27, 34_564_824_166)).size
  #=> 445635 (number of palindromes within range)
puts "Elapsed time = #{(Time.now-t).round(2)} seconds"
  # Elapsed time = 2.77 seconds
a.first(20)
  #=> [                33,  44,  55,  66,  77,  88,  99,
  #    101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191,
  #    202, 212, 222] 
a.last(10)
  #=> [34563836543, 34563936543, 34564046543, 34564146543, 34564246543,
  #    34564346543, 34564446543, 34564546543, 34564646543, 34564746543]
```

**Explanation**

(under construction)